# Gradle Sync Fails - "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base"

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-maps-api-2

Came across this issue while implementing firebase dependencies along with google play location dependencies:

> ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but
>   resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
>   tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this...

Comment: r u inside any proxy ?

Comment: Are you using `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your file? Please also add the content of the other `build.gradle` (Project) file.

Comment: @Alex Mamo, Actually, I have not added the dependencies in the module gradle, instead added it to the project gradle as mentioned above in the query. If possible can you recreate the issue by adding the dependencies to any if your project and let me know the reason for such an issue?

Comment: @Android Killer, I am not inside any such proxy network!